# How to specify order when defining a field to be an index in mongoose during schema creation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
  const animalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String,
    score: { type: [Number], index: true } // field level
  });
```

The score field is indexed, but what about the order? How can I specify that?

Comment: What order would you want other than numerical?

Comment: descending or ascending?

Comment: An index works equally well for both. Don’t specify the direction of an index in the index, but in the sort on the query

Comment: My queries will mostly always be getting the largest value. so what is the default order then?

Comment: The great thing about an index sort is the first and last items are equally efficient to find.

Comment: The server can use an index in either forward or reverse order: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-with-a-single-field-index